# Color incorrect on visited links

Tags: css

I have a problem with setting the CSS on the main page of my website, [www.speedy.net](http://www.speedy.net/). I want the link color to be `#146cc0`, which is correct when the link is unvisited. But when the link is visited, it changes to blue. I had specific CSS for `a:visited` which I removed, but I checked with 4 browsers now (Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge) and the visited links are always blue (not `#146cc0`). How do I make the visited links same color as unvisited links?

Here is the CSS of the main page:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

#top-gradient {
    height: 80px;
    background: url('/images/gradient.png');
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #146cc0;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

a > span {
    color: black;
}

a:hover > span {
    color: #FF0000;
}

a:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:active {
    color: #990099;
    background-color: transparent;
}

td {
    padding: 0px 40px;
}

.wiki-link {
    font-size: 40px;
}

img.main-image {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.speedy-bottom-badge-link {
    font-family: "lucida grande" ,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #3B5998;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
    img.fb-badge {
        width: 30%;
        height: auto;
    }
    img.main-logo {
        width: 65%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .wiki-link {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
    .speedy-bottom-badge-link {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
```

This is the CSS I removed:

```
a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #0000CC;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Thanks, Uri.

Comment: So, uh... instead of removing the rule, have you considered changing it to `color: #146cc0;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out the bug - I had to define `a` instead of `a:link`. Here is the CSS that works:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

#top-gradient {
    height: 80px;
    background: url('/images/gradient.png');
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #146cc0;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

a > span {
    color: black;
}

a:hover > span {
    color: #FF0000;
}

a:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:active {
    color: #990099;
    background-color: transparent;
}

td {
    padding: 0px 40px;
}

.wiki-link {
    font-size: 40px;
}

img.main-image {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.speedy-bottom-badge-link {
    font-family: "lucida grande" ,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #3B5998;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
    img.fb-badge {
        width: 30%;
        height: auto;
    }
    img.main-logo {
        width: 65%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .wiki-link {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
    .speedy-bottom-badge-link {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS link pseudo classes, the order matters:

```
a:link {color: blue;}
a:visited {color: purple;}
a:hover {color: red;}
a:active {color: yellow;}
```

Link, Visited, Hover, Active

L, V, H, A

LoVe, HAte

If you want to keep them all the same, you can just set:

```
a {color: blue;}
```